# Warning : Zeus Virus Detected

Tags: google-chrome, spam-prevention

It happened many times to me and every time I lose some unsaved work.

Some times I open a website that it will automatically takes me to a spam site that shows a message box that says

> Warning : Zeus Virus Detected

When I try to close the error message and close that tab, it does not let me do that.

Every time I click on OK button the same message appear again.

How can I close this spam only without closing all other tabs.

I am using Chrome.

Comment: You have ad-ware. Do you have an anti virus?

Comment: I have antivirus. but this still showing, my question is how to stop it after it appears?

Comment: Not easy. I assume you are using Windows... Which version? Usually, you'd have to track the service that's causing this, edit/remove registers, reinstall browser and it's extensions... I'll try to point you to the right solution after your OS update.

Comment: its Windows 10.

Comment: You might also want to get an adblocker. These types of scam can also be triggered by “malvertising”.

Comment: If you Google "Zeus Virus Detected", you'll find a bunch of web sites that describe how to get rid of it.  Several mention scanning with Malwarebytes and Malwarebytes AdwCleaner, both free.  They also recommend scans with other applications, some free and some not, often to make the process look unnecessarily complicated or to generate referral revenue.  They offer download links for all of the recommended products.  Don't trust their links; go directly to the the publishers' web sites.  I suspect that the two Malwarebytes products are probably adequate.

Comment: What build of windows 10?
(e.g. Build 1607) (How to: 1.  Press the windows key  + R  on your keyboard (at the same time)
2.  Type winver into the Run box (see below) then click OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close a single tab, `Ctrl + w` never failed me. If that doesn't work, open another Chrome instance + one new empty tab. Drag-drop this adware tab out to the first instance, so that you can have those two devils in the background, while you can do stuff in a new instance. If that works, so should closing the first instance with those 2 nasty tabs...

For the long term solution, I would first start with the most obvious... Check the browsers response in between those steps:

- [Remove all untrusted Chrome extensions](https://www.timeatlas.com/uninstall-chrome-extensions/).
- [Check the startup programs](https://www.howtogeek.com/162446/how-to-manage-startup-applications-in-windows-8/). Something not done by you or your everyday programs? You can remove it...
- [Uninstall suspicious Windows programs](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/uninstall-programs-windows-10). Make sure you don't remove some essential c++ or .NET library.
- [Run services.msc](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4499-start-stop-disable-services-windows-10-a.html), and try to locate the service that's running this filth on a startup. It should be set to run automatically. It may not be easy to spot it between all those unknown services, but google away... Once you do find this service, you should `disable` it, try to `stop` it, and use its `path to executable` value to get the location of the .exe file. You can try removing it, but you'll probably lack permissions to do so.
- [Boot into Safe Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode), or even better, use a `live CD/usb flash` to delete the file without the service running in the background.
- Lastly, try to remove it's settings from [Windows Registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/29cdb627-4398-b1d8-2c99-0ade53423be4/open-registry-editor-in-windows-10). Also not easy to find...

Answer (score -1):

To close the message do Ctrl + Alt + Delete and then click Start Task Manager. From there click Google Chrome and then End Task

Comment: The question was *"How can I close this spam only without closing all other tabs"*.